# Mapping the keys of a Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hashmap

I am working with a hash called `my_hash`:

```rb
{
  "2011-02-01 00:00:00+00" => 816,
  "2011-01-01 00:00:00+00" => 58,
  "2011-03-01 00:00:00+00" => 241
}
```

My aim is to get rid of the “00:00:00+00” at the end of all the keys, resulting in this hash:

```rb
{
  "2011-02-01" => 816,
  "2011-01-01" => 58,
  "2011-03-01" => 241
}
```

### What I tried

First, I try to parse all the keys in `my_hash` (which are timestamps).

```rb
my_hash.keys.sort.each do |key|
  parsed_keys << Date.parse(key).to_s
end
```

Which gives me this:

```rb
["2011-01-01", "2011-02-01", "2011-03-01"]
```

Then, I try to map `parsed_keys` back to the keys of `my_hash`:

```rb
Hash[my_hash.map {|k,v| [parsed_keys[k], v]}]
```

But that returns the following error:

```
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
```

How can I map `parsed_keys` back to the keys of `my_hash`?

Comment: The problem is that `parsed_keys` is an array, and `parsed_keys[k]` is indexing in to an array, so Ruby expects you to use an index, not a String. If you really wanted to keep your code the same, make `parsed_keys` a hash as well that is set like: `parsed_keys[key] = Date.parse(key).to_s`.

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks so much !

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Why don't you just do this?

```
my_hash.map{|k,v| {k.gsub(" 00:00:00+00","") => v}}.reduce(:merge)
```

This gives you

```
{"2011-02-01"=>816, "2011-01-01"=>58, "2011-03-01"=>241}
```

Comment: Yes that's a great a idea. But the string is "00:00:00" at some places and "00:00:00+00" at others. Can I get rid of both of these  strings using the same piece of code ?

Comment: Try regular expressions. `my_hash.map{|k,v| {k.gsub(/ .+$/,"") => v}}.reduce(:merge)` This deletes everything after a space.

Answer (score 6):

There is a new "Rails way" methods for this task :)

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys

Answer (score 3):

Building on [iblue’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11505443/578288), when removing the time from each string, you could use a regexp for `gsub`’s pattern instead of a string. For example:

```rb
pattern = / 00:00:00(\+00)+/
my_hash.map{|k,v| {k.gsub(pattern,"") => v}}.reduce(:merge)
```

You could improve the regexp pattern to handle different situations.

Comment: This will leave a white space in the key (`"2011-01-01 "`)

Comment: yep, you're right, the pattern should be / 00:00:00(\+00)+/ :)

Comment: Thanks for another solution Juan.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative could be:

1. map
2. return converted two elements array [converted_key, converted_value]
3. convert back to a hash

```rb
irb(main):001:0> {a: 1, b: 2}.map{|k,v| [k.to_s, v.to_s]}.to_h               
=> {"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`Hash#transform_keys`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys)** from the Ruby standard library:

```rb
my_hash.transform_keys { |key| key.gsub(" 00:00:00+00", "") }
```

##### When `Hash#transform_keys` became available

The method was added to the standard library [in Ruby 2.5](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/12/25/ruby-2-5-0-released/), which was released on 2017-12-25. `Hash#transform_keys` also used to be defined in Active Support starting with Rails 4.0.1 ([released](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activesupport/CHANGELOG.md#rails-401-november-01-2013) on 2013-11-01). Active Support’s definition of the method was [removed](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d5197d59a112581e8838f6867c0a02806bace46a) in Rails 6.0 as unnecessary, because Rails 6.0 depends on Ruby 2.5.